# Script to count files in subdirs based on reoccurring subdir

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm lookiong for a batch script which let's me count only the amount of files in a certain sub dir.

I have a directory tree with various projects (300+) and I am only looking for the amount of files in a reocurring subdirectory.

Currently I am using mtee(small program to revert cmd output to a txt file) and dir to count the subdirs and do a manual search in excel.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in with a batch script.

e.g: Every project has the directory proposals and subdirectory no-go proposals. I want to count the amount of files in the no-go proposals from the basis of the directorytree

Answer (score 0):

Read `HELP FOR` and `HELP SET` and try the following code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r /d %%d in (*) do (
  call :countf "%%d\nogo"
)
goto :eof

:countf
set count=0
for %%f in ("%~1\*") do (
    set /a count+=1
  )
echo %~1 has !count! files
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks, but this goes 1 dir deep. The extent to how deep the dirs go vary. some have 1 subdir to go through whilst others might have 3 or 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "startfolder=x:\proposals\no-go proposals"

set /a counter=0
for /r "%startfolder%" %%i in (*) do set /a counter+=1
echo %counter% files found in "no-go proposals" .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /s/b/a-d "c:\project"^|find /c "\no-go-dirname\"') do ECHO nogocount=%%i
```

Well, that's the line within a batch file. If you're running it from the prompt, each `%%` becomes `%`

do a directory list of all of the filenames, `/a-d` not directorynames, `/s` including subdirectories `/b` in basic form, so no headers or trailers. Filter this with a FIND and `/c` count the lines that contain the string "`\no-go-dirname\`" and assign the count to `%%i`

Comment: Close, but this will also count files that exist in sub-directories of a "no-go proposals" folder. Adding another pipe to FINDSTR with a well constructed regex before the pipe to FIND /C can properly filter the results.

Comment: From OP's comments, I thought that was what was required. Are there files in a subdirectory of a no-go subdirectory that need to be excluded? Need more information.

Comment: Agreed, more info needed. I interpret that there are many no-go folders, and the OP only wants folders within the various no-go folders. You include subdirectories of no-go folders. Either could be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Good to see so many  alternatives, and all of them works seemlessly however this is my version.

```
dir /s/b /a-d | find /c /v ""
```

running this command in a directory where you need the file count will return just the count.